# onKeyPress not producing key pressed in React-Native Windows

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm using react-native version 0.54.0 for a windows app. I have a `TextInput` element, and I'm wanting to implement `onKeyPress`. I have the following:

```
<TextInput 
ref = { this.setTextInputRef }
onChange = { (e) => this.setState({ currentString: e.nativeEvent.text }) }
onKeyPress = { (e) => { console.log(e) }}
onSubmitEditing = { () => this.doAThing() }
multiline = { true }
/>
```

In my editor, hovering over the `e` event in `onKeyPress` shows that it's a string. However, doing `console.log(e)` reveals it to be a SyntheticEvent with all of its properties being null. I understand `onKeyPress` just got working with android, is it not compatible with windows? If it is compatible, what magic do I need to do to get it working?

All of this is to listen for an enter event, so if there's an alternative, I'd be happy with that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Windows is cantankerous with this. With multiline set to true, the listener behind the scenes swallows the enter keypress event before it reaches the onKeyPress listener. Had to hack a fix in react-windows-native.